# how to fix google map center location in vue js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

hi create real estate app i have problem in google map if i call location from Json I get error Like this 
my html code

```js
name: "Property",
  data() {
    return {
      ref: this.$route.params.ref,
      propertydata: {},
      center: { lat: 45.508, lng: -73.587 },
      markers: [],
      places: [],
      currentPlace: null
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$http
      .get("http://localhost:3000/Listing/" + this.ref)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        this.propertydata = data.body;
        this.center=data.body.latitude;
        this.center=data.body.longitude;
        th
      });
```

```html
 <gmap-map :center="{lat: {{propertydata.latitude}} , lng: {{propertydata.longitude}} } " :zoom="14" style="width:500px;  height:500px;"></gmap-map>
```

```
- invalid expression: Unexpected token { in

{lat: {{propertydata.latitude}} , lng: {{propertydata.longitude}} }
```

Raw expression: :center="{lat: {{propertydata.latitude}} , lng: {{propertydata.longitude}} } "

my location details from json  how to fix this i have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to declare the component is:
`<gmap-map :center="{lat: propertydata.latitude, lng: propertydata.longitude}" :zoom="14" style="width:500px;  height:500px;"></gmap-map>`

You should use `{{...}}` syntax only inside tags, not in tag attributes.

Comment: @lgor  i didn't get any error but map is not working

Comment: It could be some issue connected to `<gmap-map>` component.

Comment: i got a console data like this 
 {"lat":"__vue_devtool_undefined__","lng":"__vue_devtool_undefined__"}

Comment: Are you sure `propertydata` is not empty?

Comment: here is the json code


      "Latitude": "25.110846",
      "Longitude": "55.377311",
  
json data call

'  data() {
    return {
      ref: this.$route.params.ref,
      propertydata: {},
      center: { lat: '25.034851', lng: '55.182095' },
      markers: [],
      places: [],
      currentPlace: null
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$http
      .get("http://localhost:3000/Listing/" + this.ref)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        this.propertydata = data.body;
        
      });
  },'

Comment: Use `:center="{lat: propertydata.Latitude, lng: propertydata.Longitude}"` then, pay attention to letters case.

Comment: here is another error from console invalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: Yup, got the problem. Try: `:center="{lat: parseFloat(propertydata.Latitude), lng: parseFloat(propertydata.Longitude)}"`. I'm not sure but it may help.

Comment: No errors but the mark icon doesn’t display on the map

Comment: marker object value is  same vale of  center value  
check the screen shot  https://snag.gy/VD4G1c.jpg